# Current PayPal Fees in web API?

Tags: api, magento, paypal

Does anyone know if there is a publicly available PayPal resource that would allow me to calculate transaction fees in my Magento code?

For example, if someone buys something for $1.00, I'd like to know if $0.15 of that is a PayPal fee.

If there were a resource, like paypal.com/currentfees.xml or something that I could readout in my PHP code, I could that. Does it exist? I know there are different fees for different payment methods (e.g., AMEX) and fees could change at any time -> So it'd be good to have a dynamic way to calculate how much of Magento's order totals are really PayPal fees.

EDIT: To clarify, I'm not interested in charging customers more, just in knowing how much of my price is going to fees. For bookkeeping.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if this applies online, but it's illegal to charge customers an added % based off the fee you are being charged. Better just to bump up the price a tad.

Comment: I'm not interested in charging customers more, just in knowing how much of my price is going to fees. For bookkeeping. Thanks

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I'll research it a little more and report back. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PayPal fees are not the same across accounts or even by transaction; there are different fees for cross-border transactions, PayPal Here transactions, large-merchant discounts, et cetera.
Have a look at https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-fees for more detail.
So no, unfortunately you can't pull a resource to find the current fee.

However, PayPal *does* return the fees paid for each transaction in the API response.
For example, if you're integrated with PayPal Express Checkout, the DoExpressCheckoutPayment API ([doc](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/doexpresscheckoutpayment-api-operation-nvp)) is used to finalize a transaction. This API call returns a 'PAYMENTINFO_0_FEEAMT' parameter which contains the total fee amount paid for the transaction.

Should you wish to retrieve this information *after* the transaction has been completed; PayPal also offers the GetTransactionDetails API call ([doc](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/gettransactiondetails-api-operation-nvp)). This API call also returns 'FEEAMT' as a parameter.
Simply submit the TRANSACTIONID and read out the FEEAMT.

Note:  Fees are only calculated on completed transactions. You won't get a FEEAMT back for any order or authorization-ID's (e.g. those starting with O-xxxxxxxx).

Comment: And this is way, way offtopic, but I'll just mention it since it might benefit you: you can also view the monthly total fees paid via the 'Monthly Financial Summary Report' on https://business.paypal.com/

Comment: Suppose someone wants to send 100 Euros to be paid from dollars. Is there a way to determine the total dollar amount to be paid, including the transaction fee, BEFORE the transaction is completed?